# Need help on changing power supply

Tags: power-supply, power

I would like to know how can I change power supply to my microcontroller in the case of power cut so I can use battery instead all this be done automatically?

Comment: Yes, search "diode OR" circuit.

Answer (score 1):

A diode in series with the battery (and another one in series with the power supply)will do the trick.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you have a lot of options, and you really need to give more detail.

One option is to just use Schottky diodes in series with your supplies. Further, if you know the exact voltage levels being supplied by your battery and PSU, you can make sure that only one supply will give current at a single time.

Another option for example is to have load switches on both your power lines and control them with the microcontroller it is powering. Place an open-drain comparator on your main power rail and hook it up to the load switches. You can also hook them up to your MCU, then when the comparator line goes low you will get an interrupt and control the load switches accordingly. Place enough capacitance on your power line so your MCU doesnt brown out before the power switch occurs.

Comment: Thank you to all for a quick response. I'll try that with schematic first and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the perfect answer but I'll try anyways :3 :

I can think of two ways to do this:

First you can connect the battery and the regular power supply to the same power line, and connect diodes from each supply but you can only do this assuming the regular supply has a higher voltage (not necessarily by much)

I'm guessing you connect both to the same ground.

Another way is using an electromagnetic (relay) switch that when turned off connects to the battery.
Directly connect the power supply to the relay,when it is ON the relay will connect the regular power supply (another power line from the same source) to the microcontroller
When the regular power supply is off the relay reconnects to a battery supply.

I hope I've made my point as clear as possible. Good luck!